# SDL Wordserver Upgrade to 11.3 for SDL Tridion 2013SP1 TM connector - User is not a member of Client test

Tags: 2013-sp1, translation-manager, worldserver

Anyone based this on an error message, On-premises SDL Wordserver upgraded to 11.3 and SDL Tridion 2013sp1 TM - connector configured with newly upgraded endpoint URL credentials and configuration on the `TranslationManager.config`, Endpoint URLs are accessible on the server. I feel something missing from the Wordserver side configuration.

```
2018-03-07T09:25:06 `Tridion.TranslationManager.Service` SendForTranslation
An error occured while processing an item: User is not a member of Client test (deleted:1033) Code: 400. Type: VALIDATION.   title: Test_Übersetzung_märz   Translation Job id: 435
User is not a member of Client test (deleted:1033) Code: 400. Type: VALIDATION. 
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.WorldServerV11.WorldServerV11Configuration.GetJsonResponse(WebRequest
webRequest)
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.WorldServerV11.WorldServerV11Configuration.Post(String
relativeUrl, String obj)    
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.WorldServerV11.WorldServerV11TranslationSystemJobRequest.PrepareTranslationJobForCompletion)
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.FinalizeTmsJob(TranslationJob
job, TranslationSystemJobRequest jobRequest, IEnumerable`1
itemRequests)
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.ProcessClient(TranslationJob job, String clientId, List`1 resolvedItems)    at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.Process()
at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.ServiceTask.ThreadMethod()Translation Job
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We fixed this issue,

In the CMS Global Parent Content Publication properties, The "**Translation**" tab Translation source configuration is not configured as highlighted values.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the solution, you say "is not configured as highlighted values", but should they be and they weren't earlier? All the highlighted values from the screenshot are read from Worldserver via the Translation Manager service.

Comment: Actually, what I came to know, they had those values previously but while upgrading they took PROD world server DB to DEV world server. and then they updated 11.3 server endpoint with T2013sp1 TranslationManager.xml then those values are gone. suspecting PROD and old DEV clients names are not in sync.

Comment: Yeah, that would explain the difference. The TM service reads all the available values from the WS endpoint defined in the config. If you haven't reconfigured those values than they would stay the old ones which might not be present in the "new" WS.

Answer (score 2):

It indeed looks like Worldserver side, please verify whether the "test" Client exists in WorldServer (Management -> User setup -> Clients). The message indicates that the Client has been deleted.

Is this for an old Translation Job created before the upgrade?

Comment: It's new job created and send for translation, I'm not sure about the old job let me double check